# Why Static content deploy in magento2

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

for less , it is meaningful to compile , 
but why js and HTML templates are also generated,

is there any significance doing that, in security and performance

Answer (score 1):

- In order for Magento to work those files need to be created at some point.
- They can either be created at run time(when needed) or before hand.
- The performance improvement becomes then more than obvious.
- There is also a security improvement as creating all the files before hand will allow you to tighten up permissions on the project in a production enviorment.

More about static content deploy in the official docs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html